# Javascript: detecting $-function in all browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an external library, that tries to detect a $-function (jquery, mootools, ...), and if it doesn't exist, will use its own, overwriting it. They do this in global scope, and there's not much I can do directly about this.

```
if ($ == null) {
    var $ = myFunction;
}
```

This works in modern browsers, but IE7/IE8 breaks. My question is how to detect the existence of $-function in all browsers reliably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (typeof(window.$) === 'undefined') {
  window.$ = myFunction;
}
```